# Show that {$a+bx+cx^2,a_1+b_1x+c_1x^2,a_2+b_2x+c_2x^2$} is a basis of $P_2$, if and only if {$(a,b,c),(a_1,b_1,c_1),(a_2,b_2,c_2)$} is a basis of ...

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-space-isomorphism

Show that {$a+bx+cx^2,a_1+b_1x+c_1x^2,a_2+b_2x+c_2x^2$} is a basis of $P_2$, if and only if {$(a,b,c),(a_1,b_1,c_1),(a_2,b_2,c_2)$} is a basis of $ℝ^3$.

Comment: What are your thoughts on this? You need to provide some context for your question so that we have some idea of what you already know and can come up with an answer you’ll understand.

Answer (score 3):

Let's look at the coordinate transformation:

$$T:\text{R}_2[x] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$$
$$T(\alpha + \beta x + \gamma x^2)=(\alpha, \beta, \gamma)$$

That's an isomorphism (why?), and as such, it transfers a basis to a basis.

Answer (score 1):

Let $S=\{a_1+b_1x+c_1x^2,a_2+b_2x+c_2x^2,a_3+b_3x+c_3x^2\}$, and $T=\{(a_1,b_1,c_1),(a_2,b_2,c_2),(a_3,b,c)\}$.

Take a vector $(p,q,r) \in \mathbb{R}^3$. Note that then $p+qx+rx^2\in P_2$.

Then

$\begin{array}{rcl}p+qx+rx^2 &=& \beta_1 (a_1+b_1x+c_1x^2)\\
&&+\beta_2 (a_2+b_2x+c_2x^2)\\
&&+\beta_3 (a_3+b_3x+c_3x^2)
\end{array}$

$\iff \left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
p=\beta_1a_1+\beta_2a_2+\beta_3a_3\\
q=\beta_1b_1+\beta_2b_2+\beta_3b_3\\
r=\beta_1c_1+\beta_2c_2+\beta_3c_3\\
\end{array}\right.$

$\begin{array}{rcl}\iff (p,q,r) &=& \beta_1 (a_1,b_1,c_1)\\
&&+\beta_2 (a_2,b_2,c_2)\\
&&+\beta_3 (a_3,b_3,c_3)
\end{array}$

So any element in $P_2$ is a linear combination of S $\iff$ any element in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is element of T.

Similar argument also can be used to show that the linear combination is unique for $S$ implies it's unique for $T$, and vice versa.